# How to take and save photo without Uiimageview (swift4)

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, photo-gallery

The following code is that standard take photo then place it on imagview then save the image on image view to the photo gallery. I want to skip the uiimageview part and just take photo and have it automatically save to the photo gallery.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageTake: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageTake.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }

    @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        imageTake.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having while trying not to use the image view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can do the following edit

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    /// useless now     
}
@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
           UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }
}}
```